# Implementing for-each on SAFEARRAY

Tags: c++, c++11, com

I've not implemented a range-based for mechanism before, and was curious how this might work for SAFEARRAY.

A possible use-case is wanting to populate a `std::vector` from a `SAFEARRAY *`. Would you need to wrap `SAFEARRAY` in a custom class providing special iterators for instance?

One issue is that `SAFEARRAY` can contain different types. Say you mapped string <--> BSTR, int <--> I4 and all other types weren't valid, how could you set up something like: `for(string s : MySafeArray)`?

We already have a wrapper class:  `template <class T> SafeArrayWrapper{...}` where `T` is the type you want the array contents treated as.

Comment: Using C++ syntax on C language types never gets you anywhere.  I suppose the world needs yet another C++ wrapper class, you'll have to write one.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question would be considered "too broad". It seems pretty specific to me... SAFEARRAY's design raises some particular nuances.

Comment: You'll need to explain why you don't know how the write a C++ wrapper.  At least post an *attempt* at writing one so we can tell what kind of help you need.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't know how to. I asked if one was required. I also explained that range-based for is not something I'm familiar with... I don't know how to fit that into my wrapper since SAFEARRAY is a bit special. Chris' answer seems good, and neatly side-steps the variable-type awkwardness, although I wondered if a template-solution could work... but there's just too many things going on at once for me to easily know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simplest way to honor the ability to enumerate strings, or integers, from a SAFEARRAY would be to create two collection classes, one to represent strings, the other to represent ints, in a safearray.

Here is something that might represent an enumerable collection of strings.

```
class SafeArrayStringList {
public:
  SafeArrayStringList(SAFEARRAY);
  class iterator;
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
};
```

Crucial to this was the (forward) declaration of an iterator, and a being() and end() method, that C++ is going to look for when you use a range based for loop on one of these.

The definition of the iterator would look like:

```
class SafeArrayStringList::iterator {
  SAFEARRAY _array;
  int _idx;
public:
  iterator(SAFEARRAY);
  iterator& operator++();
  bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs);
  std::string operator*();
};
```

This is pretty much all you need (on XCode) to satisfy the requirements for the range based for loop.

Done properly you should make your iterator extend the std::iterator class, but for the purpose of clarity I have stripped out everything that is not actually required.

To enumerate the strings in a SAFEARRAY you would

```
for(auto stringitem : SafeArrayStringList(safeArray){
  std::string foo = *stringitem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create:

1. An iterator that supports `operator*`, `operator++`, and `operator!=` overloads. Make it a sub-type of [`std::itertor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)
2. Functions `begin(SAFEARRAY&)` and `end(SAFEARRAy&)`, and their `const` variations.

Here's a contrived example that shows what you need to support range-`for` for a user defined type.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct Foo
{
   std::vector<int> vec_;
};

struct FooIterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int>
{
   FooIterator(Foo& f) : foo_(f), iter_(f.vec_.begin()) {}
   FooIterator& end() { iter_ = foo_.vec_.end(); return *this; }

   int& operator*() { return *iter_; }
   std::vector<int>::iterator operator++() { return ++iter_; }
   bool operator!=(FooIterator const& rhs) const { return iter_ != rhs.iter_; }

   Foo& foo_;
   std::vector<int>::iterator iter_;
};

FooIterator begin(Foo& foo)
{
   return FooIterator(foo);
}

FooIterator end(Foo& foo)
{
   return FooIterator(foo).end();
}

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   for ( auto f : foo )
   {
   }

   return 0;
}
```